# Как подсчитать степень каждой вершины связного неориентированного графа в программе на языке python?

Tags: python, массивы, графы, networkx

Всем привет! Буду благодарен за помощь. Имеется связный неориентированный граф (код прилагаю) нужно найти (и желательно занести данные в массив) степени каждой вершины, потому что нужно будет рассчитать центральность сети через степень близости)
Понятия не имею как это делается, есть встроенные функции в библиотеке networkx, пробовал сделать это через них, надеюсь хоть что-то из этого верно сделано.

```
import itertools
import networkx as nx
import numpy.random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import vertex as vertex


def add_nodes(nodes):  # Упрощаем добавление вершин
    for i in nodes:
        graph.add_node(i)


def add_edge(f_item, s_item, graph):
    graph.add_edge(f_item, s_item)
    graph.add_edge(s_item, f_item)


graph = nx.Graph()
add_nodes(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'))

add_edge('A', 'B', graph)
add_edge('B', 'C', graph)
add_edge('C', 'D', graph)
add_edge('A', 'E', graph)
add_edge('E', 'B', graph)
add_edge('B', 'D', graph)
add_edge('D', 'E', graph)
add_edge('C', 'A', graph)
add_edge('C', 'E', graph)
add_edge('D', 'A', graph)
add_edge('A', 'F', graph)
add_edge('F', 'B', graph)
add_edge('G', 'B', graph)
add_edge('H', 'G', graph)
nx.draw_circular(graph,
                 node_color='red',
                 node_size=1000,
                 with_labels=True)

# G = nx.Graph()
# G.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'])
# G.add_edges_from(
# [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('A', 'E'), ('E', 'B'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'E'),
# ('D', 'A'), ('A', 'F'), ('F', 'B'), ('G', 'B'), ('H', 'G')])
# cc_centrality = nx.closeness_centrality(G)

# print(cc_centrality)


deg_centrality = nx.degree_centrality(graph)
print(deg_centrality)


# close_centrality = nx.closeness_centrality(G)
# print(close_centrality)

bet_centrality = nx.betweenness_centrality(graph, normalized=True,
                                           endpoints=False)
print(bet_centrality)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете ввиду ["классическое" понимание `степеней вершин`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B_(%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2)), то в NetworkX для этого есть атрибут [Graph.degree](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.degree.html#:%7E:text=degree().,edges%20incident%20to%20that%20node.&text=The%20name%20of%20an%20edge,value%20used%20as%20a%20weight.):

```
print(graph.degree)
```

вывод:

```
[('A', 5), ('B', 6), ('C', 4), ('D', 4), ('E', 4), ('F', 2), ('G', 2), ('H', 1)]
```

Comment: Спасибо! А не подскажете как мне после этого эти данные в массив вставить?

Comment: @Слава, так они уже в массиве - это список, состоящий из кортежей. Первый элемент кортежа - имя вершины, второй - её степень.

Comment: Просто мне хотелось как-то из списка кортежей вынуть именно массив чисел который соответствовал бы каждой вершине от A до H, чтобы уже проводить операции над ними
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Слава, возможно это не мое дело, но мне кажется вам рановато работать с такими модулями как `numpy`, `networkx` и `vertex` если вы не знаете как извлечь первые элементы кортежей из списка кортежей ;)